# react native firebase fcm cloud message app is not open when user click push notification

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing with react native and evollu firebase fcm cloud messaging.
when user receive push notification and click to it, it won't be do anything, app is not opened.

How can I fix this?